# To show contacts on startup for wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am creating a phone dialer for wp7. Actually i got a sample- https://www.dropbox.com/s/hlqyhrx9aw6jwpq/Employees.zip. But in this sample, it actually downloads some datas. But what i need is instead of downloading datas, i need the default **contacts** to be shown automatically when the app is launched. The contacts visual must be like PhoneCallTask i.e, like the default windows phone 7 has. For example see the below image-

[image]

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Won't the [AddressChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.addresschoosertask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) help you out here?

It will launch the Contacts application and allow the user to select a contact. Upon completion of the task an event is raised.

To start the task:

```
var addressTask = new AddressChooserTask();
addressTask.Completed += AddressTaskCompleted;
addressTask.Show();
```

Handling the Completed event which receives an [AddressResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.addressresult%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) EventArgs.

```
private void AddressTaskCompleted(object sender, AddressResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        this.displayName = e.DisplayName;
        //...etc.
    }
}
```

Another option is to use the [Contacts type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.userdata.contacts%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). Which allows to interact / query the user's contact data. More information can be found on MSDN:

[Access Contact Data for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286416%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

If you can query the data you can build such a screen yourself, from scratch.

Query contact data:

```
Contacts contacts = new Contacts();
contacts.SearchCompleted += ContactsSearchCompleted;
contacts.SearchAsync(String.Empty, FilterKind.None, "Contacts Test #1");
```

Handle the SearchCompleted event.

```
private void ContactsSearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
{       
    MessageBox.Show(e.Results.Count().ToString());
    //...
}
```

Use the fetched data to build your own custom screen.

Comment: But i want AddressChooserTask in the beginning(when the app starts). I want that as the first page for my app.

Comment: Actually i dont need the search option at all, i want to choose the contacts directly from the contacts list.

Comment: Not at home right now, so can't test WP development. Can't you just start the AddressChooserTask as your application launches?